# PHP Undefined Variable Qk Fix

Tags: php, variables, undefined

Getting an `undefined variable: pay` error.

It still puts out the paycheck amount... I just want the notice to go away.
Provide new code if any please :)

```
$hours = (int) $_GET["hours"]; 
$wages = (int) $_GET["wage"]; 

$overtime = max($hours - 40, 0); 
$pay += $overtime * $wages * 1.5; 
$pay += ($hours - $overtime) * $wages; 

echo "Hours Worked: " . $hours . "<br>"; 
echo "Pay rate (per hour): $" . number_format($wages, 2) . "<br>"; 
echo "Overtime Hours: " . $overtime . "<br>"; 
echo "Your Paycheck is: $" . number_format($pay, 2) . "<br>";
```

If you need any more info than what I have provide please let me know. I dont think I need to post the html stuff etc. Thanks again!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1):

Either initialize e.g., `$pay = 0;` above the `+=` assignment or else change the first to `=`. For example:

```
$overtime = max($hours - 40, 0); 
$pay = $overtime * $wages * 1.5; // <--- change += to =
$pay += ($hours - $overtime) * $wages;
```

The reason you got the error was because the `+=` operator means "add the value on the right to the value of the **existing** variable on the left, then assign the sum to the variable on the left. So the `$pay` variable needs to be initialized first to use the `+=` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line (undefined variable is raised because $pay is not inicialized):

```
$pay = 0;
```

after:

```
$hours = (int) $_GET["hours"]; 
$wages = (int) $_GET["wage"];
```